# Difficulty opening an .x86 file

Tags: xrandr, executable, shared-library

I was trying to execute an .x86 file and got this message:

```
./build.x86: error while loading shared libraries: 
  libXrandr.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty new to Linux, so I don't know what to do. Any solutions?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your system 32 or 64 bit ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package `libxrandr2`. This package includes the missing file `libXrandr.so.2`